# Why doesn't "let readIndex:0" cause a TypeScript compile error?

Tags: typescript, compiler-errors

I accidentally added the following code to my TypeScript program, meaning to type `let readIndex=0`:

```
let readIndex:0;
```

From this, the TypeScript compiler produces the following JS code:

```
let readIndex;
```

Why did compilation not fail? I wouldn't have expected this to be even valid syntax, as `0` is not a valid type name, but clearly I'm wrong.

What, then, does this syntax mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 0 is not a valid type name

0 is a [numeric literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#numeric-literal-types), so it's valid syntax. It's somewhat confusing, and it's not really useful as a 'singleton' numeric literal type, because usually these types appear as elements in a union type like `0 | 1`, but the syntax is what it is.